Typeorm migration fails with `beforeInsert()`
I am on an ESM project where I have a db model that looks like this. My end goal here is to create an issuance record immediately when an application has been created.
@Entity()
export class Application extends BaseEntity {
    ...other fields

    @AfterInsert()
    @AfterUpdate()
    async createAndLinkIssuance() {
        if (this.status === "approved") {
            const issuance = await CredentialIssuanceService.create({
                application: this,
                credentialId: this.credential.id
            });
            this.credentialIssuance = issuance;
        }
    }
}


the CredentialIssuanceService.create method just creates an entity in the database using the repository patter like this
async create(entity: DeepPartial<T>): Promise<T> {
        const entityCreate = this.repository.create(entity);
    await this.repository.save(entityCreate);
    return entityCreate;
}


when I run this code, everything goes well, but when I try to migrate, it doesn't want to and gives an error
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Application' before initialization
    at file:///Users/merul/Desktop/Projects/auvo/server/src/services/index.ts:7:53
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:431:15)

The BeforeInsert hook doesn't seem to want to work here, removing the hook fixes the error.
How can I either fix this, or achieve the same result in some other way?

Seems like typeorm did not like myservice in the hooks, replacing it with repository there did the trick :)
